# Two Ribbon buttons pointing to same View Model

Tags: wpf, module, wpf-controls, prism-4

I have a Module,Within the module .I need two Ribbon buttons "Create" and "Edit".Both these buttons point same View and ViewModel.The only way i can distinguish these is using the command parameter property part of Ribbon Button.I am using Navigate View to move to the View.I want to pass additional parameter to ViewModel constructor saying the invoke is from Create or Edit.Any suggestions??

Answer (score 0):

You need create two diferentes Commands in your ViewModel:

1- CommandEdit    --> Asingned the `CommandProperty button Edit` by binding;

2- CommandCreate  --> Asingned the `CommandProperty button Create` by binding.

Is not good idea shared logic in the shame command behavior.

Answer (score 0):

RibbonButton has a Tag property:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windows.controls.ribbon.ribbonbutton.ASPX
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.tag.ASPX

When defining the buttons, you can set Tag property for each ribbon button. You can then extract Tag value in your event handler and react accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I would bind `Create` and `Edit` buttons two different `Commands` e.g. `CreateCommand` and `EditCommand`. I would pass any additional details about the caller in the corresponding Execute methods of the Command.

Sample Code:

```
void CreateCommandExecute(object o)
{
   YourMethod("Create", o);
}

void EditCommandExecute(object o)
{
   YourMethod("Edit", o);
}

void YourMethod(string caller, object commandParameter)
{
   // Your logic goes here
}
```